# Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that I can run perfectly in Visual Studio 2010.

It simply creates some files in a location  - I:\FileOutput.

When I set the package to run via SQL Server Agent it fails with an error  -

Executed as user:DOMAIN\svc-SQLReleaseOne. Microsoft(R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.6615.2 for 64-bit
Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format

The user has full read/write permission to the location of the dtsx project and also the file output location?

What else can I check please?

Comment: And which SQL Server are you running? 2012?

Comment: Are you loading XML or creating XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down in the end to needed the full UNC path of where the file output was to saved.